# Are my BTC now BCH?! What happened?! Is my money lost?

Tags: client, bitcoin-cash, kraken

i don't know if i made a big mistake. I start from the beginning:

I wanted to transfer my BTC (worth 350$) to kraken. Accidently i sent them to a BCH address. You can see it here:
https://blockchain.info/tx/45c843c767b5ff8543adacb900c13fc03289639216c9de0862cb5ee8b41a863b
It got enough confirmations and so I wrote the kraken support whether they could help me to get my btc back. but then i realized that blockchain.info now showed that i would have the amount i sent to kraken now as BCH which was of course much less (50$) . I couldn't find out on which address i got the money because blockchain.info wasn't able to show on which address i got the money, it only showed that i have 50$ in total as BCH.
I read about how to get my money back to BTC, so I transfered my money to my wallet in EXODUS as BCH (blockchain.info only offered this transfer method) to a BCH address. It again got confirmations:
https://blockdozer.com/insight/tx/63be7ff8d38e648c19a1d0a9dc66a87ee64ae1359888ac8404b017d82c607dc4
I now have the 50$ on my BCH address in exodus, but this tool wasn't able to get my money back to BTC. I used this tutorial:
http://support.exodus.io/article/189-ive-sent-bitcoin-cash-to-my-bitcoin-address

is it possible to get the money back to BTC or is my money now forever BCH? Please help me. The one to help me get my money in BTC back, gets a little donation.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're saying is true, this sounds like a big problem.

BTC and BCH are two completely separate blockchains.  It's impossible to send bitcoin from one to the other.

If you send BTC to an address, then it's always going to be an address on the **BTC blockchain**, not the BCH blockchain.

So if you sent your BTC's to address X, then you sent them to address X on the **BTC blockchain**.  If you don't own address X on the BTC blockchain, then you no longer have access to those funds.